# JobService doesn't stop after calling FirebaseJobDispatcher.cancel()

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher, jobservice

I have `JobService` where I register broadcast receiver to listen to screen on/off events. The registration happens in `onStartJob()`.
If I leave the device idle for a couple of minutes, and then call `cancel("jobTag")` of `FirebaseJobDispatcher`, I see that `onDestory()` and `onStopJob()` are called. However, if I leave the device idle for a few hours, if I call `cancel("jobTag")`, I don't see the calls for `onDestory()` and `onStopJob()` and the `JobService` continues to run. How can stop the JobService even if the device was idle for hours?